# EWS: is it possible to prevent appointment modifications on ExchangeServer?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, undo

I use EWS 2.0. Is it possible to prevent appointment modifications on ExchangeServer programmatically? or is there some way to undo change/delete?

Comment: Short answer: no. Who are you trying to prevent from making a change? The mailbox owner, a delegate, etc? Do the appointments have meetings? If they are appointments with no attendees, you could have a service monitor the calendar for changes to items and then have the service undo the changes.

Comment: thanks, i have a monitor and catch changes. But i need to prevent it for spetial appointments. How can I use exchange server "UNDO" with EWS 2.0?

Comment: Who are you trying to prevent from making a change? The mailbox owner, a delegate, etc? Do the appointments have attendees?